# How to implement Dapr Subscriber in .net Windows Service?

Tags: dapr

I need to implement the Dapr Subscriber in the windows service, I am able to implement it in Asp.Net API. But not in Windows service, Is there any workaround to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a trick to implementing this in windows service.

We need to add a controller

```
[ApiController]
public class DaprController : ControllerBase
{

    public DaprController()
    {
    }

    [Topic("pubSubName", "topicName")]
    [HttpPost("/topicName")]
    public ActionResult ProcessData([FromBody] string data)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Also, we need to add a startup.cs file like this.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace Publisher
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers().AddDapr();
            services.AddLogging();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseCloudEvents();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapSubscribeHandler();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And add the below code in the Program.cs file.

```
.ConfigureWebHostDefaults((builder) =>
                {
                    builder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                })
```

**Reference:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/dapr-for-net-developers/publish-subscribe#use-the-dapr-net-sdk