# Dapr subscriber not working for Azure EventHub in C#

Tags: azure-eventhub, dapr

I am implementing subscriber in C# for Azure event hub, But it's not working.

There is no error in the logs, What could be the possible reasons for failure?

My code could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70304998/6527049).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the issues, I was using the event hub namespace key, But I had to use the key and connection string from the Shared Access Policies from the Event Hub.

There was one more issue, in command `dapr run --app-id <consumer group name>`, app-id should be the consumer group name of the event hub.